# Error when convert english number to arabic number C#

Tags: c#

i need to convert my english number to arabic number to store in database
when i use this code to code

```
  public static string ConvertNumerals(string input)
  {
        UTF8Encoding utf8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        Decoder utf8Decoder = utf8Encoder.GetDecoder();
        StringBuilder convertedChars;
        convertedChars = new StringBuilder();
        char[] convertedChar = new char[1];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 217, 160 };
        char[] inputCharArray = input.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in inputCharArray)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                bytes[1] = Convert.ToByte(160 + char.GetNumericValue(c));
                utf8Decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, 2, convertedChar, 0);
                convertedChars.Append(convertedChar[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                convertedChars.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return convertedChars.ToString();
  }
```

return string when convert it to int64 appeare this error ???

[image: Error Pic]

Comment: Please don't post your error as an image. Many of us are on networks that can't access sites like imgur, making it impossible to help you. Copy and paste it into the body of your question.

Comment: Most likely the error is that you need to include an `CultureInfo` instance with the `Convert.ToInt` as your currently executing CultureInfo on the executing Thread does not match the string you are trying to parse.

Comment: To be able to trace down your issue, first change your system number to english, so you don't get confused if the val is arabic or english number

Comment: I think this is a trick question since English uses Arabic digits unless you are asking about eastern arabic.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Answer (score 0):

Try this method 

    `public static string ConvertNumerals(string input)
    {
        char[] inputCharArray = 
        input.ToCharArray().Where(ch=>char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray();
        var newCharArr = new string[inputCharArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i<inputCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var c =  inputCharArray[i];

            newCharArr[i] = char.GetNumericValue(c).ToString();
        }
        return string.Join("", newCharArr);
    }`